# Relay access denied when not send from server itself

Tags: postfix, centos6, dovecot

I'm setting up Postfix & Dovecot on CentOS 6. Everything works except sending mail from withing Outlook to someone else. Receiving works & sending from ssh console as well ..

I've been searching for 3 days now ...

This is the error in /var/log/maillog:

> Oct  5 16:11:55 072297 postfix/smtpd[5442]: warning: 55.55.55.55: address not listed for hostname 55.55.55.55.my.isp.hostname.tld
>   Oct  5 16:11:55 072297 postfix/smtpd[5442]: connect from unknown[55.55.55.55]
>   Oct  5 16:11:55 072297 postfix/smtpd[5442]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[55.55.55.55]: 554 5.7.1 <me@hotmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<me@domain.com> to=<me@hotmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<MePC>
>   Oct  5 16:11:58 072297 postfix/smtpd[5442]: disconnect from unknown[55.55.55.55]

This is my main.cf (running 'postconf -n'):

> alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
>   alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
>   broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
>   command_directory = /usr/sbin
>   config_directory = /etc/postfix
>   daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
>   data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
>   debug_peer_level = 2
>   home_mailbox = Maildir/
>   html_directory = no
>   inet_interfaces = all
>   inet_protocols = all
>   mail_owner = postfix
>   mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
>   manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
>   mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
>   mydomain = domain.com
>   myhostname = mail.domain.com
>   mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
>   myorigin = $mydomain
>   newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
>   queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
>   readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
>   sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
>   sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
>   setgid_group = postdrop
>   smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
>   smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
>   smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
>   smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
>   smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
>   unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

And this is my dovecot.conf (running 'dovecot -n')(Added a quote in front of hashtags, bugged the script parser):

> '# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
>   doveconf: Warning: NOTE: You can get a new clean config file with: doveconf -n > dovecot-new.conf
>   doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:84: add auth_ prefix to all settings inside auth {} and remove the auth {} section completely
>   doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:86: passdb pam {} has been replaced by passdb { driver=pam }
>   doveconf: Warning: Obsolete setting in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:88: userdb passwd {} has been replaced by userdb { driver=passwd }
>   '# OS: Linux 2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
>   auth_mechanisms = plain login
>   disable_plaintext_auth = no
>   listen = *
>   mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
>   mbox_write_locks = fcntl
>   passdb {
>     driver = pam
>   }
>   passdb {
>     driver = pam
>   }
>   protocols = imap pop3
>   service auth {
>     unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
>       group = postfix
>       mode = 0660
>       user = postfix
>     }
>   }
>   ssl_cert = 
>   ssl_key = 
>   userdb {
>     driver = passwd
>   }
>   userdb {
>     driver = passwd
>   }
>   protocol pop3 {
>     pop3_client_workarounds = outlook-no-nuls oe-ns-eoh
>     pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
>   }

A very big thank you to anyone that can help me with this !

Comment: # postconf mynetworks ? # postconf smtpd_recipient_restrictions ?

Comment: used to have mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8 but that didn't work either, smtpd was never in there

Comment: Reinstalled everything, only got Relay Access Denied now .. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your SMTP server settings in Outlook, and ensure that you have set the correct port of 587 (not 25!) and that you use the correct username and password.

Comment: Well I can't post images yet, but this is my Outlook configuration: http://puu.sh/4HE2p.png . How did you know I used 587 ? :O Everything in Outlook is correct, as clicking 'Test Account' succeeds.

Comment: 587 is the standard port for authenticated outgoing mail from an end-user.

Comment: Well 25 was the default in the beginning but I changed it to 587 because for some odd reason my server didn't accept incoming connection .. adding to firewall didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the 'The SMTP server needs authentication' fixed this, actually a bit stupid.
It is disabled by default.